# evitar recarga de formulario después de enviarlo

Tags: reactjs

estoy realizando una función de login, sin embargo al dar click en enviar formulario este se recarga automáticamente a pesar de tener la función `preventDefault();` el código de enviar submit es este

```
  onsSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const user = {
      username: this.state.username,
      password: this.state.password,
    };
    this.props.login(user);
  };
```

también intenté con `stopPropagation();` y obtengo el mismo resultado, asimismo, cuando envío el formulario la información digitada se muestra en la barra de navegación.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mostranos el componente entero asi vemos como es la estructura del formulario.

Comment: Un tiro al aire, pero ¿existe la posibilidad que lo tengas mal escrito? tu función la tienes definida como `onsSubmit`, pero quizás donde asocias la función estás llamando a `onSubmit`?

Answer (score 0):

Hola una vez que se da submit, el formulario apuntara a la url que tengas en el atributo action si tiene "/" como action o nada, apuntaria al sitio raiz del formulario, para evitar que se envio el formulario el onsubmit, tienes que dispararlo en una accion que puede ser el hacer click al "submit", luego si el boton se llama submit, cambialo a "submit-button" o algo distinto porque ocasiona conflictos con la funcion nativa "submit" de JS. Si no quieres ver los parametros en la URL cambia el atributo method del formulario a method="post", sino agregas ningun metodo, el metodo por defecto es "get", que es el envia los parametros en la url, entonces, paras el envio de datos, y haces la validacion por una llamada AJAX.